# Amazon linux 2023: package installation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux-2023

I am trying to intall falcon on Amazon linux 2023 ami, but getting the error as, Problem: conflicting requests
nothing provides libnl needed by falcon-sensor-6.54.0-15110.amzn2.x86_64

now when i am trying to install falcon using the command,
sudo yum makecache --refresh
sudo yum -y install libnl.x86_64

getting the error as,
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-86-65 ~]$ sudo yum -y install libnl.x86_64
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:42 ago on Thu Dec  7 13:34:45 2023.
No match for argument: libnl.x86_64
Error: Unable to find a match: libnl.x86_64

can anyone help me out. My main goal is to download falcon successfully.

Comment: should probably ask this on server fualt?